# Security break to shell

Tags: shell, centos7

Our server had a break-in and the hacker left this trail (my server hang with this message on the screen)

```
sh-4.2# eboot
sh: eboot: command not found
sh-4.2# rebooot
sh: rebooot: command not found
sh-4.2# reboot
sh: reboot: command not found
sh-4.2# restart
sh: restart: command not found
sh-4.2# logout
sh: logout: not login shell: use 'exit'
sh-4.2# ^C
sh-4.2# ^C
sh-4.2# ^C
sh-4.2# exit
exit
```

My 'lastb' and 'last' show nothing wrong/peculiar except my fail2ban block few IP addresses.

We are using Centos7. Any advice how to prevent this from happening in the future?

Thanks.

Comment: It is sad to say, but I resort to blocking entire ranges from APNIC and AFRANIC address blocks. There are ranges from RIPE I exclude as well. There are many good solutions, but I find `iptables` to be about the easiest and most foolproof.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We already have a few /8 denied in iptable (firewalld). Well, may be doing a whitelisting is not a bad idea :(